# Invalid flag to regex error on button click in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, web

I have a view in which a quiz is displayed using an external js file.  When the quiz is completed, I am appending some new html to the screen, including a new button that is suppose to, upon being clicked, send the user to the practiceTask function of my Main controller.  However, when it is clicked I get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'practiceTask'
```

Because the code is in .js file, I can't use site_url or base_url, as far as I know.  Is this the correct way to do this?

Relevant JS:

```
$('#imageLocation').attr("src", "");
var html = '<div class="instruction_block"><p class="instruction_text" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0">You have completed the ' + text + ' test</p><div class="button_placement" style="margin-top: 300px;"><input class="rounded" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 250px;"" type="button" value="Continue to the next task" onClick="/main/practiceTask/3"></div>';
$('#final_message').append(html);
```

Main Controller function:

```
public function practiceTask($task_id){

$this->load->model('Main_model');

echo ($task_id);

$json_key = $this->Main_model->getKey($task_id);
$json_key = json_decode($json_key, true);

shuffle($json_key);

$data['test_key'] = $json_key;
$data['task_id'] = $task_id;

$this->load->view('practice_test_view', $data);
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a value into a JS page, you can put it into a hidden input and parse with JS on the page load so that it is available for you to use.

The problem you might be having is with your onclick

```
onClick="/main/practiceTask/3"
```

do this with jQuery

```
var html = '<div class="instruction_block"><p class="instruction_text" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0">You have completed the ' + text + ' test</p><div class="button_placement" style="margin-top: 300px;"><input class="rounded" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 250px;"" type="button" value="Continue to the next task" data-url="/main/practiceTask/3"></div>';
$(document).on('click', '.button_placement input', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    window.top.location = $(this).data('url');
 });
```

This way it creates an event that will trigger whenever you click on the button. It will read the data-url value and redirect you to that page.

Good luck ;)

Comment: That did it. Thank you for the clear and concise answer.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Not a problem, glad i could help :)